# How to use data from an array to plot a graph and store it in a file

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I am solving a differential equation using shooting method and Runge-Kutta integration. Therefore, my Java code will generate lots and lots of data which I will be storing in arrays. I will use these arrays of data to plot many, many graphs, which I want to store in files on my D drive for analysis.

I was wondering if I should learn how to plot graphs in Java and store them in files or if I should use third-party software like JFreeChart. What's your opinion on the matter?

Also, I see that JFreeChart is very popular, but are there some such softwares geared especially for scientific numerical computation?

Comment: Not sure if you want to integrate the charting with your application (via say, a button) or you want the charting to be executed from a separate tool. Here is a list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_information_graphics_software and http://www.cohort.com/coplot.html, of course so many others exist.

Comment: I would like to integrate the charting with my application. Basically, I would like to add a few lines of code to my program which, when run, would take the data from the array or linked list, plot a graph and store in a location in my D drive that I will specify in my code.

Comment: writing a good charting library is not a trivial task. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: I do not want to write an entire charting library. I only want to plot x-y graphs and store them in my hard drive for analysis. I was  wondering if writing the code for that that would be a difficult task. If it is, then I should use one of the libraries instead. What's your opinion on the matter?

Comment: Well, I did, in the end, use JFreeChart. I have added their JAR files to my classpath and run their sample codes and looks like it does the job well. Thank you for your comments.